# Web UI for Raspberry Pi with PHP script to send data over serial pins

Tags: php, apache, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I am currently building a project using a Raspberry Pi 3. I am using Apache as a web server to host a php website. A few of the pages need to send a command to the serial port of the pi. When ssh into the pi and use minicom (to test my functions) all commands work perfectly. When I put those commands in my web page php script I get garbage (some of the data comes along with additional characters). An example a command is "m123456". Below is a sample of my php script, I used the sleep function to mimic the time between keystrokes when I ssh and use minicom to type the command. Could someone help please.

```
<?php
echo system("echo 'm' > /dev/ttyAMA0");
sleep(2);
echo system("echo '1' > /dev/ttyAMA0");
sleep(2);
echo system("echo '2' > /dev/ttyAMA0");
sleep(2);
echo system("echo '3' > /dev/ttyAMA0");
sleep(2);
echo system("echo '4' > /dev/ttyAMA0");
sleep(2);
echo system("echo '5' > /dev/ttyAMA0");
sleep(2);
echo system("echo '6' > /dev/ttyAMA0");
?>
```

Comment: Does ```echo system("echo 'm123456' > /dev/ttyAMA0");``` give the same extra characters?

Comment: When I type echo system("echo 'm123456' > /dev/ttyAMA0"); I get the same problem.

Comment: The exact same characters? Same strange characters between each character echoed?

Comment: I played around with the sleep time and got it to work with sleep(1);